# app:layout_constraint values always displayed as undefined in xml source view - Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, undefined-symbol

My layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="profile"
            type="android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData&lt;myapp.UserProfileDetails&gt;"/>
    </data>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewProfileContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context=".UserProfileEditActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewProfileAvatar"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_square"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="@{profile.name + ' ' + profile.lastName}"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Display1"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewProfileAvatar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageViewProfileAvatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:text="@string/label_profile_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewProfileAvatar"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@={profile.name}"
            android:maxLength="15"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/label_profile_last_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:text="@={profile.lastName}"
            android:maxLength="30"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView12"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:text="@string/label_profile_phone"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText5"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:maxLength="32"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:text="@={profile.phone}"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</layout>
```

What's the problem? Every property like `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageViewProfileAvatar"` is highlighted red in source view, for example:

> Cannot resolve symbol '"@+id/imageViewProfileAvatar'

The same goes to to all app:layout_constrait... properties above. However, designer seems to be fine, code compiles fine and app works fine.

This started after updating to Android Studio 3.2. Do you have any idea? Pretty annoying. I tried: rebuild app, invalidate cache, resync to gradle, nothing helped.

[image]

Constraint layout is added in build.gradle as follows:

`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'`

Comment: Did you try to clean the project before rebuilding it ?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my question

Comment: That's what you mean by "invalidate cache" ?

Comment: Nevermind, I tried to celan before build, even id I did not mentioned it clearly in my question. It does not help. Invalidade cache I mean option File->Invalidate Cache & Restart

Comment: You should mentionned it but nevermind. Can you post your build.gradle line for the constraint layout ?

Comment: Question updated. I know this is not latest version (latest is 1.1.3), do you think this could be reason?

Comment: Yes maybe ! I know that there were some similar issues that have been resolved by downgrading to the 1.0.2 version. Try to upgrade to the latest version first. If it's not working, try the 1.0.2 version

Answer (score 0):

add the follow dependency to (app/build.gradle)

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'